# /usr/local: No such file or directory

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I have a new mac mini with snow leopard.

When I enter the following into the terminal: `cd /usr/local` I get this error message: `-bash: cd: /usr/local: No such file or directory`

I am not sure why?

Comment: The directory does not exist.  Why don't you believe the error message?  If you need it, create it.  sudo mkdir /usr/local

Comment: Why do you expect it to exist?

Answer (score 4):

You're getting this error because the directory /usr/local does not exist.  I don't have a Snow Leopard install in front of me right now, but it's entirely possible that this directory doesn't exist by default -- nothing would be installed there in a stock install.

Comment: `/usr/local` doesn't exist by default on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in the terminal instead:
    ls /usr

This lists the contents of the /usr directory.

Do you see "local" is in the list of directories in /usr?  If not, it doesn't exist and that's why you can't cd to /usr/local.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to create the directory /usr/local you can enter
>

> sudo mkdir /usr/local

You will need to enter your password, because the directory /usr is most likely owned by the user root.  This command will warn you and do nothing if /usr/local already exists.

Answer (score 0):

By default (and thus on new installations) there is no `/usr/local/`. 
This explains why you get the message **No such** file or **directory**.

If you want to create it go to /usr and use mkdir local.  (or, if the logged in account has insufficient rights: `sudo mkdir /usr/local`.